# How to find duplicate column values in same database table?

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

In this scenario there's only one table. And column is MOBILENUMBER. This contains some numbers which are duplicate. 
e.g. There're some numbers starting with '0' i.e. 09898123456 and some without '0' 9898123456.

In a way, both are same number. I want to find those numbers which are duplicate by removing the leading '0'

The table contains almost 16 million records. I don't want db to be locked for some time. The query should be such that it should not go into infinite loop otherwise it is Live data.

Thank you.

Comment: (a) Oracle always uses non-blocking reads, no need to worry about locking in this scenario (b) if the query is based on ordinary tables it cannot go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `MOBILENUMBER` column to `Integer` to remove the leading zero's

```
Select * from
(
Select Count(1)Over(Partition by cast(MOBILENUMBER as INTEGER)) as Cnt,
       MOBILENUMBER 
From Yourtable 
) A
Where Cnt > 1
```

If you would have kept the datatype as `INTEGER` with `unique` constraint on it then you wouldn't have got this problem in first place

Am not very sure about locks in Oracle. In Sql Server the `Select` query will just acquire a `Shared` lock so the object can accessed by another transaction.

Comment: Thanks @Prdp but I would like to know what "over(Partition by cast(MOBILENUMBER as INTEGER)" will do? As this is Production data and I cannot change the column type just like that.

Comment: @Advait - It will not alter any data this is just a `select` query.

Comment: Regarding locking, look at `transaction isolation level`. I don't know Oracle either but in MS SQL it is `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED` and I remember that in Oracle is `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ SNAPSHOT` default. But maybe someone will correct me.

Comment: Actually, I want to consider the row as duplicate when one row has mobilenumber 09898123456 and other row has mobilenumber 9898123456. The above query does not handle that I think.

Comment: @Advait - Above query will return both `9898123456` and `09898123456`.

Comment: It does, as integers doesn't have leading zeros.

Comment: @MarekVitek: Oracle does not support dirty reads (`read uncommitted`) and it doesn't have to, because readers never block other transactions in Oracle

Comment: Hi, @Prdp, the query works perfect on dummy database. However, while running on actual db it throws below error:

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number. 

Which means there're some MOBILENUMBERS which are string also. The current type is VARCHAR2 (400 CHAR)

Can you help me what should be in query now? Should there be some changes in casting?

Comment: Hi @Advait, if you're getting ORA-01722 you may want to consider my approach instead, which does not rely on converting the data to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize your data to have the leading zero and match on that, e.g.:

```
select m, count(*) as dup_count from (
  select lpad(t.mobilenumber,11,'0') as m
  from mytable t
)
group by m
having count(*) > 1;
```

The advantage of this approach intead of converting to a number is that it will not fail on any rows that happen to contain non-numeric data.

Notes:

1. Oracle uses non-blocking reads, you don't need to worry about locking
2. The query might be slow depending on the volume of data, but it will never be "infinite".

Answer (score 0):

use this please ;

```
create table dup_table1 as
select to_number(t.MOBILENUMBER) mob_number, count(1) dup_count
  from table1 t
 group by to_number(t.MOBILENUMBER)
 having count(1)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join to match these. With this version any prefix can be used. When you need to match numbers based on international prefix `+1` for US instead of 0, then just replace `'0'` with `'+1'` and it will match +12345 and 2345.

```
select * from phones as p
join phones as p1
    on p.phone = '0' + p1.phone
```

**EDIT:** Previous example works fine with MS SQL. Here is proper version suited for Oracle.

```
select * from phones p
inner join phones p1
on p.phone = concat('0', p1.phone)
```